# CSS buttons in Loop

Tags: php, html, css, loops, radio-button

I have this css being used  for radio buttons.

```
input[type=radio]:checked + .selectionName{
    border:4px solid #fcaf17;
}
```

This worked fine with this code in my view:

```
<label class="option" for="option2" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    <input id="option2" type="radio" name="option" value="Loved Quality of Purchase" />
    <div class="selectionName"></div>
</label>
<label class="option" for="option3">
    <input id="option3" type="radio" name="option" value="Someone solved my Problem" />
    <div class="selectionName"></div>
</label>
<label class="option" for="option4">
    <input id="option4" type="radio" name="option" value="Other" />
    <div class="selectionName"></div>
</label>
```

But it stopped working when I put the view code in a loop:

```
<?php foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
<label class="option" for="option1">
    <input id="option1" type="radio" name="option" value=<?php echo $option['title'] ?> />
    <div class="selectionName"><?php echo $option['title']; ?></div>
</label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In the loop only the first radio button option is clickable and displays the border.

Some more of the css code for the radio buttons:

```
.option > input[type=radio]{
    display:none;
}

input[type=radio]{
    cursor:pointer;
    border:4px solid transparent;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .selectionName{
    border:4px solid #fcaf17;
}
```

How do I fix this to work in the loop

Comment: What html code does the foreach loop produce?

Comment: The foreach code prints the list of radio buttons. So for every item in the loop, a radio button is displayed for that item

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: It looks like your foreach loop only produces buttons with `label id=1`, but that is I think only a problem if you want to do something with the buttons, not with the styling.

Comment: Please show us the HTML code that the PHP code outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your foreach loop only produces buttons with `label id=1`. Since CSS id's needs to be unique only the first element is recognized. Try changing the variable name in the foreach loop as well.

```
<? var i = 1; ?>

<?php foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
<label class="option" for="option + <?php i ?>">
    <input id="option + <? i ?>" type="radio" name="option" value=<?php echo $option['title'] ?> />
    <div class="selectionName"><?php echo $option['title']; ?></div>
</label>
<?php i++ ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I do not speak php so you might have to change the syntax a bit.

Comment: Just got it with something similar. I set a counter and incremented withing the loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo:

```
<input id="option1" type="radio" name="option" value=<?php echo $option['title'] ?>/>
```

Should be:

```
<input id="option1" type="radio" name="option" value="<?php echo $option['title'] ?>"/>
```

You are missing the "".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't really causing a problem. And it doesn't help the problem. But thanks